# read XML via jQuery (read the variable)

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, variables, cdata

I can directly read the XML Feed using jQuery, but when I display the return XML doc using 'console.log', the 'description' tag only show '#cdata-section' in console, but it is able to display full content when I put them into the HTML. The output is a full content of a article, like below 'Sample Content'.

**Sample Content:**

```
<p> line 1 line 1 line 1</p>
<p> line 2 line 2 line 2</p>
<img src='..' />
<p> ... ... </p>
```

Now, if I retrieve it via .ajax using jQuery, I will use a 'desc' variable to hold this 'description' node (which holding above sample content), but how I read how many 'p' or 'img' element in this 'desc' variable?

I want to get the what element inside this 'desc' variable, my objective is to read the img tag. is there a way to do it? Note: before put into the body of the HTML.

**XML:**

```
<channel>​
 <title>​Property​</title>​
 <link>​</link>​
 <lastbuilddate>​Wed, 13 Oct 2010 23:50:51 GMT​</lastbuilddate>​
 <generator>​FeedCreator 1.8.0-dev (info@mypapit.net)​</generator>​
 <atom:link href=​"sample.com" rel=​"self" type=​"application/​rss+xml">​</atom:link>​
 <item>​
  <title>​sample title​</title>​
  <description>​
    #cdata-section
  </description>​
  <pubdate>Wed, 08 Dec 2010 23:04:25 GMT</pubdate>
 </item>​
<channel>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "http://feed6.xml",
 dataType: "xml",
 success: function(xml) {
  console.log(xml);
  $(xml).find('channel').each(function(){
   $(this).find('item').each(function(){
   var desc = $(this).find('description').text();
   console.log(desc);
  });
 });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one.....

```js
$(xml).find('channel').each(function(){
   $(this).find('item').each(function(){
      var desc = $(this).find('description').text();  
      var newTag =document.createElement("div");  
      newTag.innerHTML = desc;
      var imgTag = newTag.getElementsByTagName("img");
   });
});
```

Comment: yes, I think it work, but let said if I got multiple img tag inside the content, how should I get the first one?

Comment: if you have multiple image tag then newTag.getElementsByTagName("img"), will return array....so just iterate this using for loop, you will get all img tags...and if you have tags other than img,then you can get those tags in same way as i did for img tag.....please accept this answer if you find its working for you...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is in this line:

```
var desc = $(this).find('description').text();
```

Instead of using .text() at the end of that line, try .html() and then search for the tag you want:

```
var desc = $(this).find('description').html();
var theImageYouwant = desc.find('img');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find("description");` will return you a jquery wrapped XML fragment.

Assuming the content isn't cdata wrapped, you can use jquery traversal just as you would html.

```
e.g. $(this).find("description").find("p").each(function() { // whatever });
```

If it is cdata wrapped, then unfortunately jQuery doesn't support a html() like function for xml, but you can unwrap the jquery object and then rewrap the description xml node. Something like this:

```
var content = $($(this).find("description")[0].nodeValue);
```